# Analysis jvm core file?

Tags: java, jvm, coredump

I hava a web service running on a unix server, after some update of the code, the service generate a core file core.94489 when starting up, anyone knows how to analysis this core file to debug the problem? Thank you.

PS: I use oracle jvm7

Comment: Did you noticed you have hs_err* file as well?

Comment: @SMA No. Just the core file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @SMA suggests, the hs_err{pid} file will have most of the things you need (or can make use of)

IMGO The core dump isn't useful unless you have a debug build of the JVM e.g. you built the OpenJDK for DEBUG.

Comment: @cheng in that case, I would check the core dump really is a JVM core dump as these are disabled by default. It sounds like a C/C++ program which has failed e.g. it should be the program you use to launch the web service. Can you open it with `gdb` to see which command it was running.

Comment: I started up the service in debug mode, just now I update the debug port and the problem is gone... Anyway, thank you for helping...

Comment: @cheng I suspect a process what already using that port.  I would check there is no older version of the service still running.  You can use `netstat -a  -n` on Unix to see if any process is using that port.

Comment: It turns out to be that a process I started before is not shutdown...but the error given by jvm (the core file) is really bull shit...

Comment: @cheng agreed, a core dump is not even an error, it's got to be a bug. It shouldn't core dump because it couldn't get a port.